# How to load properties from resources folder?

Tags: java

I've been able to get the following to work by loading a properties file which exists in the same folder as the class files (the bin folder)

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

I want to load the config.properties file from a resources folder which is at the same level as the bin folder. If I pass it "resources/config.properties" it finds the file in /bin/resources, but passing it "/resources/config.properties does not look above the bin folder like I want.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Properties` like this:

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  InputStream resourceStream = Your_Class_Name.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"))
   props.load(resourceStream);
```

Comment: I tried that but resouceStream is null after it's created.  I have the resources folder at the same level as the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

`class.getResourceAsStream` method loads from jars and folders defined in your classpath. If you have that `config.properties` file under `resources` folder, you should add that folder in your classpath.
Something like

```
java -classpath "resources" ...
```